# Carbon fiber chip

Tags: carbon, preventative-maintenance

See the white mid picture in the shape of a canine tooth.  The sticker / veneer came off / separated.  Is it something I should worry about?  Is there something I can do?  Niner Air Nine Carbon.
[image: Chip]

I got a response back from Niner

> Thanks for being part of the niner nation!   That looks like some rock
>   strike which is no big deal in that area.   Ride On!

Comment: I've looked at that picture several times, and I still can't see the chip.

Comment: Well, "mid picture" is just to the left of the bottom bracket flange, and that's all black,  I see a discoloration on the end of the downtube, adjacent to the bottom bracket.  I've never studied carbon frames very closely, but it appears to be a spot where the gelcoat has flaked off.  I'd have considerable difficulty believing it's a structural problem.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Yes I think you have found what I describe as the white mid picture.  I am not worried that it is an immediate structural problem today.  I am wondering if I need to repair the chip and if so how.

Comment: I sent an email to Niner and will stop by the local Niner shop and report what I find out.  Carbon fiber is awesome I am just learning how to maintain it.  What I call a sticker may actually be a carbon fiber layer.

Comment: For me that looks like a plastic protection sticker, just there to prevent little stones from damaging the carbon. In that case the problem would purely be an optical one.

Comment: @linac I looked at it again and it may just be plastic protection.  It has a bit of a pattern in the plastic but it may be just for cosmetics.  Please post that as an answer in case it turns out to be the answer.

Comment: If it is carbon and not jet black that means there is bridging in the fibre and the area which is sheering off if just resin. I would also indicate that the area is much weaker than is was engineered to be. Most people have stated its a cover of some sort. Have you unbolted is to look at the area underneath?

Comment: @user95786 I don't know what "unbolted is to look at the area underneath?" is.   And Niner told me not to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with the comment from linac

Looks like a plastic protection sticker, just there to prevent little stones from damaging the carbon.